# Timing diagram generator

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Does anyone know a tool that creates a timing diagram based on execution of C/C++ code?

Comment: This question is not precise enough. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you mean, but Visual Studio contains some good [performance analysis tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728806%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). You can get information (like inclusive and exclusive time spent in functions) which is helpful for finding performance hotspots in your code. There are of course many other tools depending on what you are trying to achieve, I suggest looking at the [List of C/C++ tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools#C_and_C.2B.2B) on Wikipedia as a starting point.

[image]

Comment: This looks like its for .Net only.

Comment: The picture is from the MSDN and only an example. I've used it on C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how much time the computer spends executing each function I believe you are looking for a profiling tool.  Google should point you towards one that will work with your tools (compiler, debugger etc).

Check out this link on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29)